# Finding SharePoint List/Site dependencies

Tags: sharepoint-online

As a preface, I've inherited a SharePoint intranet with no documentation or handover and the company would like to tidy up unused sites/lists etc...

I was a SharePoint admin around the 2010/2013 release but haven't touched it much since. I don't remember there being an easy way of discovering dependencies on lists or even sites, and I can't seem to find anything online.

So, my question: Is there a way I can safely delete a list/document library/site with the knowledge that I'm not breaking a webpart in a different part of the instance?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to check if there are lists/documents  use the current list/document  as a web part?

If so, I recommend you adding “?contents=1” behind the lists/documents URL to access Web Part Page Maintenance page, to check if the page use the relevant list/library.

Comment: Yeah, so if I want to delete a list for example, how do I know that there's not a webpart or whatever consuming the contents of that list somewhere else?